# Default Query String in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Bit of an odd question, but I'd like to have a query string set on all of my URLs. If the parameter isn't set (or is empty), then I'd like to redirect to include a default.

For example:

```
example.com would need to requrect to example.com?param=a

example.com?param would also need to redirect to example.com?param=a
```

If the param is set and is part of a list of known values, then it should carry on as normal:

```
example.com?param=(a|b|c|d) would go to the respective page a,b,c or d
```

Some pages of the site use other parameters to sort and paginate, so the rules cannot assume that this is the only query string.

I've tried a couple of things, but kept getting stuck in a redirect loop. This is trying to set the default param:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)param=(a|b|c|d)($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rq=$1&param=a [L,QSA]
```

The main CMS rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/*(index\.php|blog|admin\/assets|site\/assets|robots.txt|sitemap(|\-[0-9]+)\.xml|products.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)param=(a|b|c|d)($|&)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/*(index\.php|blog|admin\/assets|site\/assets|robots.txt|sitemap(|\-[0-9]+)\.xml|products.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%{QUERY_STRING}&param=a [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/*(index\.php|blog|admin\/assets|site\/assets|robots.txt|sitemap(|\-[0-9]+)\.xml|products.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's almost there. I had to alter the first rule to read
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rq=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&param=a [L]
When the param is not set, I need it to append this to the URL in the address bar. Is this possible?

Comment: change [L] to [L,R=301] (use 302 while testing though).

Comment: Thanks, this is adding the param, but I need to hide the ?rq= part. Basically, I want it to rewrite the URLs but just append the ?/&param= part. Is that even possible?

Comment: You should add it to the rule I provided. Could you tell what was wasn't working with it? (since you had to alter it)

Comment: My mistake - your code was fine. The problem I have is that I need the param in the URL all the time - it needs to append itself (once set) to every link on the page so that the value is passed each time. I think I should open a new question. Thank for your help

Comment: Just add the R=302 flag. It should be fine, as far as I can see.